# FileOutputStream appending issue, where I am going wrong?

Tags: java, file-handling, fileoutputstream

I am trying to get a 3 to 5 PDF file(from some internet source) & merging them one after another.
FYI, I dont want to use iText or any other PDF lib, because, please look at the code once

```
public static void saveFile(String[] urls, String fileName) throws IOException {
    ClientURLConnection clientURLConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        int t = 1;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName,true);
        for (String url : urls) {                
            clientURLConnection = new ClientURLConnection(url);
            clientURLConnection.setHttpMethod(ClientURLConnection.GET_METHOD);
            inputStream = clientURLConnection.getInputStream();
            outputStream.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            System.out.println((t++) + " - File inserted in " + fileName + "\n");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
            outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

String[] urls - is an array of URL's to get the PDF document.
Sting fileName - is a single file to store all PDF's in it.
ClientURLConnecion - is my own class to handle proxy and other things.

Expected Output - Two PDF's which we get from URLs to be in a single file

Actual Output - Second PDF is overwriting the first one, but the size of the file is sum of the size of two PDF's.

Problem - Even I made FileOutputstream - append true, it is overwriting.
I don't understand where I'm doing wrong

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are closing the output stream in the middle of the loop. I have a hard time believing that it even works as you said, without raising an exception. Anyway, if you deal with PDFs, use a library that understand them. Just appending the files together is unlikely to get you the desired results.

Comment: Thanks to answer
I tried, even if i keep that "outputStream.close();" out of the loop it is behaving the same

Answer (score 2):

Merging two PDF files is not equivalent to appending the binary content of those files.

Your code *may* append the bytes the way you want -as suggests the size of the output file-, but it seems that only the last appended file is read by your PDF reader when you open it.

Therefore, you **probably should** use an API to read the actual content of the PDF.

Comment: Yes, My PDF reader is showing that the last appended file.
So now i got the way, "Merging two PDF files is not equivalent to appending the binary content of those files."
Thanks.



Edited:
Could you please share any links to know more about, why
"Merging two PDF files is not equivalent to appending the binary content of those files."

Comment: No problem. I hope it has been helpful.

Comment: Could you please share any links to know more about, why "Merging two PDF files is not equivalent to appending the binary content of those files."

Answer (score 0):

> WHY Merging two PDF files is not equivalent to appending the binary content of those files?

Every document file (be it a .doc, .ppt or .pdf) would have a file format. The extension of the file denotes the format in which the data has been encoded. Here by encoded I mean the structure in which the bits and bytes of the file have been written to the disk.

Every file would contain the actual data as well as some headers that define meta-data for the file. For e.g. a .doc file would have some meta data about the author among other several things. How all these fields (their order etc.) are stored on disk depends on the file format. This is why MS Word would not be able to read a PDF because it's probably expecting an entirely different set of fields.

Now, if you merge the following two PDF files

```
[pdf: meta data header]       [pdf: meta data header] 
  [pdf: page1]          with    [pdf: page3]
  [pdf: page2]                  [pdf: page4]
[pdf: meta data footer]       [pdf: meta data footer]
```

using a basic File I/O merge you'll get something like

```
[pdf: meta data header]
  [pdf: page1]
  [pdf: page2]
[pdf: meta data footer]
[pdf: meta data header]
  [pdf: page3]
  [pdf: page4]
[pdf: meta data footer]
```

which is not correct. There can't be multiple headers and different programs would behave differently. In your case, your PDF reader is happy with showing you the last PDF merged.

If on the other hand (as suggested by others as well) you use a third party API that has explicit support for editing PDF files (like iText) you'll probably get something like this after a merge

```
[pdf: meta data header]
  [pdf: page1]
  [pdf: page2]
  [pdf: page3]
  [pdf: page4]
[pdf: meta data footer]
```

which your PDF reader would have no troubles in displaying correctly.